# Как через Jquery видоизменить содержимое тега?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при помощи Jquery взять содержимое одного тега и вставить в другой + отредактировать содержимое?

Пример: нужно дату из класса `review-date ("17 ноября 2018")` превратить в  "2018-11-17" и перезаписать содержимое `itemprop="datePublished"`, т.к. дата в разметке должна быть в формате ISO 8601. И так пройтись по всем блокам страницы.

Сам код:

```html
<div class="product-review">
 <div itemprop="review" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Review">
  <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="17 ноября 2018">
 </div>
 <div class="stars-date">
  <div class="review-date">17 ноября 2018</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Какой смысл после рендеринга менять мета-информацию?

Comment: @РустамГимранов вы вообще не спите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписываем данные:

```js
let old_date = $('.product-review > div > div').attr('data-date');
console.log('old_date:', old_date);
let update_date = $('.review-date').text(old_date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-review">
  <div itemprop="review" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Review">
    <div itemprop="datePublished" data-date="17 ноября 2019"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stars-date">
    <div class="review-date">17 ноября 2018</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Чтобы изменить формат даты, данные с сервера выгружайте с английскими названиями месяцев или используйте [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/):

```js
moment.locale('ru');

console.log(
  moment('17 ноября 2018', 'DD MMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  moment('16 июля 2019', 'DD MMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/ru.js"></script>
```